# NLog adding a database schema name

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, nlog

I am unsure if its possible to add a database schema to NLog. I have tried this method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="C:\temp\internallog.txt">
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="C:\temp/${shortdate}_logfile.txt"
            layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}"/>


    <target xsi:type="Database" name="database"
            connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AppDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=AppDBUser;Password=PSSWRD!"
            commandType="StoredProcedure"
            commandText="[AppDB].[ASTONE.EventLogs]">
        <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
        <!--<dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>-->
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

However, this gives me this error:

> Error DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Error when writing to database.
>   Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not
>   find stored procedure 'AppDB.ASTONE.EventLogs'.

I have looked through the NLog wiki but it doesn't seem to have anything as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from memory, but I think your `commandText` value would need to be this:

```
commandText="[ASTONE].[EventLogs]"
```

The separating `.` needs to be *outside* the square brackets.

Since you specify the database name in the connection string, you shouldn't need it as part of the command text.

**UPDATED WITH NEW INFORMATION**

Since `ASTONE.EventLogs` is a table, you will need to write a stored procedure to insert your parameter values into it.  That's your missing piece.

Here's an example stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [ASTONE].[LogEvent] 
(
   @message nvarchar(max),
   @level   int,
   @logger  nvarchar(1024)
)
AS 
  INSERT INTO [ASTONE].[EventLogs]
  ( message, level, logger )
  VALUES( @message, @level, @logger)
```

I am guessing about the layout of your `EventLogs` table and the types and definitions of the parameters.

And then your `commandText` attribute would look like this:

```
 commandText="[ASTONE].[LogEvent]"
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for replying. Unfortunately when  I try your method I get this error: Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The request for procedure 'EventLogs' failed because 'EventLogs' is a table object.

Comment: AH!  Then that is your core problem.  (I wondered whether `EventLogs` was a stored proc: it sounded like a table name!)

Comment: `NLog` uses a `SqlCommand` object. That represents a call to a stored procedure, or (sometimes) a SQL `insert` or `update` statement.

Comment: You will need to write a stored procedure that takes your parameters and inserts records into `EventLogs`, and put that procedure's name in the `commandText` tag.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping. I have another question. Do I just put that as a comment? I'm unsure of where to put the command

Comment: "that" being the stored procedure?  Or the `commandText` attribute?

Comment: If you're asking about the stored procedure: it would need to be created in the `AppDB` database through whatever database tools you are using. Or by your group's DBAs.

Comment: If creating a stored procedure is off the table, due to rules or limited access, we can probably do the same thing without one. But it will require some research because I'm not sure what convention NLog uses for specifying embedded parameters in SQL statements.

Comment: Ah Okay. I understand now. Thank you so much!